# How can I use CAML query with List WebService

Tags: caml-query, rest

```
    var soapEnv =
            "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'> \
                <soapenv:Body> \
                <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'> \
                    <listName>Tasks</listName> \
                    <query><Query><Where><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value></Neq></And><And><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Waiting for Inputs</Value></Neq><Neq><FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>On Hold</Value></Neq></And></Where></Query></query>\
                    <viewFields> \
                        <ViewFields> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Title' /> \
                            <FieldRef Name='Status' /> \
                             <FieldRef Name='DueDate' /> \
                        </ViewFields> \
                    </viewFields> \
                </GetListItems> \
                </soapenv:Body> \
                </soapenv:Envelope>";

    $.ajax({

        url: url + prjName + "/_vti_bin/lists.asmx",
        type: "POST",
        dataType: "xml",
        data: soapEnv,
        complete: processResult,
        contentType: "text/xml; charset=\"utf-8\""
    });
```

Above isMY caml query, but doesnt give me desired output.Is there any character limits in using CAML query??

Comment: What is the output? And is this SP2010 or SP2013/SPO?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your query is wrong. It should be

```
<Where>
    <And>
        <Neq>
            <FieldRef Name='Status'/><Value Type='Choice'>Completed</Value>
        </Neq>  
        <And>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>Waiting for Inputs</Value>
            </Neq>
            <Neq>
                <FieldRef Name='Status' /><Value Type='Choice'>On Hold</Value>
            </Neq>
        </And>
    </And>
</Where>
```